# Get a rid of SqlConnection, which remains in Activity Monitor after being closed/disposed

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm creating database, using ADO.NET. Basically, I'm executing SQL commands in next way:

```
private bool ExecuteSqlCommand(string command)
{
    var success = true;

    using (var connection = GetSqlConnection())
    {
        if (connection == null)
             return false;

        using (var myCommand = new SqlCommand("query", connection))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                myCommand.CommandText = command;
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                success = false;
                Log.LogMessage(string.Format("Unable to execute SQL command: {0}", ex.Message));
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

GetSqlConnection just gets some proper SqlConnection with connection string like

```
"Server={0}\\{1};User Id={2};Password={3};Application Name={4};"
```

It works well, and executes command properly, with one exception - according to Sql Manager Studio activity monitor, it remains as active connection even after method was executed.

According to question [Why does my SqlConnection remain in the SSMS Processes list after closing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555833/why-does-my-sqlconnection-remain-in-the-ssms-processes-list-after-closing-it), this is correct behavior, since connection might be reused. But the serius issue is, that later, `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` command will be called for this database, while using different SqlConnection. Which leads to exception, since `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` requires, that connection, which is used to call this command, should be the only connection to database.

I can't reuse this connection for further operations with database, since I use different connection string for them, with database specified as InitialCatalog (obviously, I can't use it, while database doesn't exist).

So, can I somehow remove this initial connection?

Comment: try this one: [SqlConnection.ClearPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearpool)

Comment: @Rafal, why?? why would you need to touch connection poll at all for this. I don't see this is anyway related to C# ... rather how the connection get manages at DB end probably.

Comment: This is how connection pool works, it stores connections to database as open after dispose to minimize opening closing processes.

Comment: Well, ClearPool seems to work for my purpose. Once it is called after command execution, it no longer remains in Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute [SqlConnection.ClearPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearpool) This will mark all connections to be discarded instead of recycled.